# memory error in predict_on_batch() on large data set

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a test set of 18000 examples.

```
Χ_test.shape: (18000, 128, 128, 1)
```

I have trained my model and want to use predict on X_test.

If I try to just use:

```
pred = model.predict_on_batch(X_test)
```

it gives a memory error.

I tried something like:

```
X_test_split = X_test.flatten()
X_test_split = np.array_split(X_test_split, 562) # batch size is 32
pred = np.empty(len(X_test_split), dtype=np.float32)

for idx, _ in enumerate(X_test_split):
    pred[idx] = model.predict_on_batch(X_test_split[idx].reshape(32, 128, 128, 1))
```

but it either gives me memory error again or it gives me error about the reshape (depending on variations I am trying in the above code)

I have the same problem using `predict_generator` also.

Comment: what happens when you use `predict`?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal:The same.memory error (out of memory)

Comment: what was the batch size you kept while using predict?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal:It was 32 .

Comment: @George Do you get memory errors if you predict on only one sample, i.e. `model.predict(X_test[0:1])`?

Comment: @today:No, I am not getting any errors, it runs fine.

Comment: @George Then that's it. Your machine does not have enough memory. You need to use smaller batch sizes ( < 32, since you mentioned it does not work).

Comment: @today:Ok, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @today:Ok, it works like this!There is  little memory left though but at least I can run predict.(make answer please).Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP, I am posting my comment as an answer and try to elaborate more:

It seems your model size is big and therefore you need to either use a smaller batch size (< 32, since you mentioned it does not work with 32) or modify the model and decrease the number of parameters (e.g. removing some layers, decreasing the number of filter or units, etc.).